# Can magit pull hunks from another commit into my branch?

Tags: magit, git

I have a big commit on another git branch. I'd like to "cherry-pick" some hunks from that commit into my current branch. I bet magit can do that, but I'm not sure how. Anyone? (I've seen ways to cherry-pick whole commits, but I want to do it hunk by hunk.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, it's almost too easy. Just go to the other commit in the log buffer, show it, and use "a" to apply each change to the current working dir.